# How to correctly build docker container for C++ app with a shell script required to define environment?

Tags: docker

I have an executable C++ application which can only be run and used after sourcing a bash
script in order to set up the shell environment (only Linux systems):

```
$ . setupenv.sh
$ my_app
```

Normally, the setupenv.sh script is sourced in the user's .bashrc or .profile so that they can run the app from the command line.

For a few years I have been generating docker images for my app (as part of CI) with a
Dockerfile which ends with

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

CMD source setupenv.sh && my_app
```

which is OK but I want to be able to do

```
(1) $ docker run my_docker
(2) $ docker run my_docker bash
(3) $ docker run my_docker [some arguments to be passed to my_app]
```

With the solution presented above, only (1) works.
(2) launches a bash shell in the container, but the environment is not set: I would want the environment to be set up in this case i.e. have setupenv.sh be executed.
(3) just doesn't work at all.

I have read and re-read the doc and searched everywhere for answers, I sort of understand that some kind of ENTRYPOINT/CMD combination is required, but I cannot get this to work.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: To make 2 __and__ 3 work, your script has to handle `bash` as argument. You need an `entrypoint` script though.

Comment: OK, so what does that mean exactly?

Comment: What does what mean? You need a script as entrypoint which sets up the environment and then either starts bash or your application, passing all arguments it got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty typical use of an *entrypoint wrapper script*.  The basic trick here is that you can specify both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD`, and it's easier to override the `CMD`.  Only the `ENTRYPOINT` runs but it gets [passed the (possibly overridden) `CMD` as arguments](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact).  The (POSIX) shell command `exec "$@"` will replace the current process with the command line from the arguments.

So your basic script could look like

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# (prefer a plain POSIX shell if possible)

# Read in the environment file (avoid bash-specific `source`)
. ./setupenv.sh

# Switch to the main container process
exec "$@"
```

In your Dockerfile, make this script be the `ENTRYPOINT`, make the actual thing you want to run be the `CMD`, and do not set `SHELL`.

```bash
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must be JSON-array syntax
CMD ["my_app"]                  # can be shell syntax also
```

This should cover your first two cases.  If you want to pass additional arguments then the easiest way is to repeat the command.

```bash
docker run -d my_image
docker run --rm my_image env
docker run --rm -it my_image bash
docker run -d my_image my_app --with-options
```

The script can do whatever it likes, including examining the command before it runs it.  The [`node` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/node) of note tries to run a command as a Node script if it doesn't resolve as a command, though this can be confusing.  If you want to support passing options without a command, a simpler approach could be to see if it looks like the command starts with an option; for example

```bash
case "$1" of
  -*) exec my_app "$@" ;;
  *) exec "$@" ;;
esac
```

```bash
docker run -d my_image --with-options
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I have finally got this working with some slight modifications to your solution (see below)!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestions of @david-maze above, I have got this to work the way I wanted. There are some slight modifications compared to the initial suggestions:

- in my Dockerfile, I have

```
WORKDIR /
COPY entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
```

therefore I had to modify the `ENTRYPOINT` command to

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

in case the container is run with e.g. `-w $HOME` (after of course mounting the `$HOME` disk inside the container);

- my `setupenv.sh` script is strongly bash-dependent, therefore I had to use

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in the `entrypoint.sh` otherwise the syntax is not understood by `/bin/sh`.

Finally, in order to treat all 3 of my use cases above, including in fact the
2 versions of case (3) which are (i) passing an argument of type '--option' or (ii) passing an argument which is the name of a data file to open or a macro file to execute, I modified the suggestion of @david-maze like so:

```
case "$1" in

  -*)
    exec my_app "$@"
  ;;
  
  *)
   if [ -x "$1" ]; then
      exec "$@"
   else
      if [ -x "$(which $1)" ]; then
         exec "$@"
      else
         exec my_app "$@"
      fi
   fi
  ;;
  
esac
```

Now I have exactly the behaviour I wanted:

```
(1) $ docker run my_docker      => run app
(2) $ docker run my_docker some_exec => run shell or other executable with environment set up correctly
(3) $ docker run my_docker --some-option => run app with given option
(3+)$ docker run my_docker some_file.dat => open file in app
```

Thank you!